# How to use UMat in opencv3 to train face recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am sorry that my English is so bad.

I have already included the header file:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "opencv/cv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::face;
```

I declare the variable like this:

```
vector<UMat> images;

vector<int> labels;

Ptr<BasicFaceRecognizer> modelPCA = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
```

Read the picture to UMat:

```
for(...) {
    UMat t_image = imread(t_imagePath.toStdString(), 0).getUMat(ACCESS_FAST);
    images.push_back(t_image);
    labels.push_back(label);
}
```

But when I was training:

```
modelPCA->train(images, labels);
```

That post a error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The data is expected as InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT (a std::vector<Mat>) or _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR (a std::vector< std::vector<...> >).) in asRowMatrix, file C:\opencv\opencv_contrib-3.2.0\modules\face\src\face_basic.hpp, line 43
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:\opencv\opencv_contrib-3.2.0\modules\face\src\face_basic.hpp:43: error: (-5) The data is expected as InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT (a std::vector<Mat>) or _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR (a std::vector< std::vector<...> >). in function asRowMatrix
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe opencv doesn't support it yet

```
if(src.kind() != _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT && src.kind() != _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR) {
    String error_message = "The data is expected as InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT (a std::vector<Mat>) or _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR (a std::vector< std::vector<...> >).";
    CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, error_message);
}
```